# Php json string object to php array

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I've looked at how to [decode a string here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) however it requires the key's be wrapped in quotes and my data doesnt, example:

The below data, is saved in a .txt file, I'm using `file_get_contents()` to read the files, I do not have control over the below data.

**THIS IS MY DATA**

```
"{
    ip : "192.168.1.110",
    startFrame : "1",
    endFrame : "11",
    startedCurrentFrameAt: "1397529891",
    status: "rendering",
    currentFrame: "0"
}"
```

In php, I want to be able to read this data, and access each key, this is what I've tried:

```
$arr = json_decode($data, true)['status'];
```

$arr just returns null, because the key's aren't quoted, is there a work around for this?

I've found many answers to this question, but all have the key's quoted.

Comment: Are you generating the JSON or are you getting it from somewhere ?

Comment: can you add json generated code also?

Comment: From 2.2. Objects

An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members). A name is a string.

and from 2.5. Strings

A string begins and ends with quotation marks.

So those would technically be objects, which json does'nt support. the keys need to be strings my friend

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I have edited my question, I'm basically reading a txt file which the data is automatically populated.

Comment: @AwladLiton I'm not generating the object, it's automatically pulled in through a .txt which I do not create/manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for this.

---

#### Well what is happening in the code ?

First, the regular expression is trying to find the entries between a space and a `:` , and then concatenates the quotes around them. Finally, an `str_replace()` acts a wrapper to fix the JSON braces.

```
<?php

$json='"{
    ip : "192.168.1.110",
    startFrame : "1",
    endFrame : "11",
    startedCurrentFrameAt: "1397529891",
    status: "rendering",
    currentFrame: "0"
}"';

function cb_quote($v)
{
    return '"'.trim($v[1]).'":';
}
$newJSON=str_replace(array('"{','}"'),array('[{','}]'),preg_replace_callback("~ (.*?):~","cb_quote", $json));
echo $arr = json_decode($newJSON, true)[0]['status'];
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
rendering
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/136727)

#### Through a file.. (Edit)

```
<?php
$json = trim(file_get_contents('new.txt'));
//Modifications..
$json = str_replace(array('{','}',':',','),array('[{" ',' }]','":',',"'),$json);
function cb_quote($v)
{
    return '"'.trim($v[1]).'"';
}
$newJSON=preg_replace_callback("~\"(.*?)\"~","cb_quote", $json);
echo $arr = json_decode($newJSON, true)[0]['status']; //"prints" rendering
```

Comment: I am still getting null with this, I can't define the $json variable like you have, to try and replicate, would I just write this `$json = "'" . $data ."'";` ??

Comment: If you are getting that from a text file , simply do ... `$json = trim(file_get_contents('yourjsonfile.txt'));`

Comment: newJSON is defined, but if I just return `$arr` like so: `return json_decode($newJSON, true);` it is null...

Comment: Why in the world are you using `return`? Are you inside a `function` or what ?

Comment: I beleive it's formatting my string wrong, I've just seen in newJSON it's being formatted like so: `"{ip"":""192.168.1.110",startFrame":""1",endFrame":""11",startedCurrentFrameAt":""1397529891",status":""rendering",currentFrame":""0"}"`

Comment: Can you link me the text file ?

Comment: This worked better than the other answer I accepted, although, if you remove the square brakets, you don't need to go another level, I've edited your answer.

Comment: @ShannonHochkins, I tried to approve but community says rejected. weird... I think since it was very minor , It got rejected. Please give a shot once more.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php
 function fix_json($s) {
  $s = preg_replace('/(\w+):/i', '"\1":', $s);
  return $s;
}


$data = '{
    ip: "192.168.1.110",
    startFrame: "1",
    endFrame: "11",
    startedCurrentFrameAt: "1397529891",
    status: "rendering",
    currentFrame: "0"
}';

$valid_json = fix_json($data);
$arr = json_decode($valid_json , true);
$status = $arr['status'];

echo $status;
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/136717)

Comment: Please3 read my whole question, I do not have control over the quotes around the keys, unless I use a regex to add them.

Comment: My object is wrapped in "" not '', why does this matter? It doesn't seem to work unless it's single quotes not double

Comment: I eventually got this working, it wasn't work because I had spaces in my data`key : "s"`, I used another expression to remove the any spaces before a semi colon and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by using the [PHP explode](http://www.php.net/explode) function. Explode is like javascript's .split function, in that it will take a string and EXPLODE it into an array of usable data.

So, something like this should work, but you'll need to remove the "{ and }" on the ends first:

```
// lets assume that your data is $mydata, for brevity's sake.
$mydata_arr = new Array();
$item_arr = new Array();
$newdata_arr = new Array();

$mydata_arr = explode(',',$mydata); // explode where there is a comma

foreach($item in $mydata_arr){
    $item_arr = explode(':',$item); // explode where there is a colon
    // this gives us keys and values in a the $item_arr at [0] and [1]
    $key = $item_arr[0];
    $value = $item_arr[1]; 

    // reassign these in a new, usable array     
    $newdata_arr[$key] = $value;
}
```

Now, I know this is crude and inelegant, but I wanted to explain in a way that would help you see what needs to be done in something like English. I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't know where, but I believe there's an error somewhere, I can't get this to work :(

Comment: Have you removed the starting and ending bits? That would mess it up.